# How to make font-size responsive with foundation framework?

Tags: html, css, fonts, zurb-foundation

While using foundation framework, I need to make font-size responsive.!The website has two columns 8x4. I have navigation and other links in 8 columns. The height of this block is stable. But, In the 4th column I have description and while opening in the different windows size I am seeing the different height of the description. I want that the height remain constant while changing the size of the screen by increasing the font proportionately.

I have tried media queries and assigned different font percentage for different screen size. 150% for max-width 1500 and font-size: 200% for font-size. But with this other features provided by foundation framework changes. Like paragraph bottom margins

I even tried vh, vw but same problem comes up. Please suggest some way to solve this issue.

[Layout of the site](http://goo.gl/ZA6DmD)

Answer (score 1):

I think article might help you, 
http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Or what you can do it start with a layout which supports equal + full height columns. Examples:

[Equal Height Columns](http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-equal-height/)

[Full Height Columns](http://codepen.io/jagehring/pen/vxJCL)

```
_
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using vm/wh units...

**vw, vh and vmin** (Copied from [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/))

These new properties allow you to scale font sizes according to the viewport dimensions, i.e.

1vw is 1% of the viewport width

1vh is 1% of the viewport height

1vmin is the smallest of 1vw and 1vh

---

For example, assume your browser viewport is set to 1,000 x 1,200 pixels:

1.5vw = 15px font size

1.5vh = 18px font size

1.5vmin = min(1.5vw, 1.5vh) = 15px font size

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: these things are not working properly with the mobile and different screens though its really effective at times but not that lucrative while using it for fonts.